# React use outside functions as methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have some functions that I need to use in several components so I put them in a module like this.

```
export default class FormFunctions {
  handleChange (event) {
    const changedOne = event.target.name
    const newValue = event.target.value
    const newState = {}
    newState[changedOne] = newValue
    this.setState(newState)
  }
  handleSubmit (infoToPass, toThisMethod) {
    Meteor.call(toThisMethod, infoToPass, function () {
      console.log('userCreate call callback')
    })
  }
}
```

How can I use them as methods for my components?

I tried it like this but it doesn't work. And well I am not sure if I need any classes at all.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Register from './Register.jsx'
import FormFunctions from './FormFunctions'

class RegisterLogic extends Component {

  render () {
    return <Register
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      />
  }
}

export default RegisterLogic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work by making two small changes to your code:

1. Instead of this.handleChange, you will have to use `FormFunctions.handleChange` . To be able to refer the function from the class, you can add static to its definition: `static handleChange (event) {` or create and use an object of the class.
2. For whatever reason, you call a `.bind(this)` to tell react components which function to use for something, so your code becomes `handleChange={FormFunctions.handleChange.bind(this)}` .

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. Won't work because you can't access `this` in statics. That's why they are statics.

Answer (score 2):

Can you put the functions in a higher component and pass them down? Basically [lift the state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) if the logic is going to be the same in multiple.

There is a way to extract them as functions in a util file and then bind them to your class but I don't recommend this, I found it was much better to use a state management file like Redux instead (tiny file size, and other huge benefits).

If you use a state management system like Redux then you can have the `setState` functionality as a reducer (just a normal function). You would then be able to call other reducers from this reducer and this logic would be available to all components you wish.

Comment: I didn't learn Redux yet however lifting the state up seems a solid and an official solution to this but I am not sure how to do it with React Router, maybe you can provide an example?

Comment: @HaykSafaryan I haven't used React Router before

Comment: There seems to be lot's of problems with React Router for this with no official solution.